# AWS Lambda Iterator age alarm is never triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We have a CloudWatch alarm set for AWS Lambda Itereator age that for some reason is never triggered. Even though the iterator age definitely exceeds the threshold. Here is part of our CloudFormation template that is used for this alarm:

```
"TreatMissingData": "missing",
"ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
"Dimensions": [{
    "Name": "FunctionName",
    "Value": {
        "Ref": "LambdaFunction"
    }
}],
"EvaluationPeriods": 1,
"InsufficientDataActions": [],
"MetricName": "IteratorAge",
"Namespace": "AWS/Lambda",
"OKActions": [{
    "Ref": "NotificationTopic"
}],
"Period": 900,
"Statistic": "Minimum",
"Threshold": 1800000,
"Unit": "Microseconds"
```

Comment: Isn't just the statistics supposed to be Maximum?